# Recovery or installation drive for windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I want to nuke my windows 10 installation and replace it with linux (dual boot is not an option), but want to be able to restore it to windows at some point in the future.

Should I create a recovery drive or a full installation drive (with the media creation tool)? Also, are there hidden partitions that I should preserve?

Comment: No; Anyone can download a Windows 10 ISO.  Your Windows 10 license is likely using a digital entitlement, check Microsoft's documentation to determine if thats the case, even in the case of a physical license the process is the same.  You simply install Windows 10.  If you are going to replace Windows 10 with Linux you should format the HDD and all partitions and allow the Linux installation to create which partitions it wants

Comment: @Ramhound that's probably it, thank you. Sometimes one just overlooks the simplest solutions

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your scenario:

> If you want to return to the current Windows 10 state (with all your
>   data, pre-installed software etc)

You need some 3rd party tool that can backup the HDD content completely (CloneZilla is a nice free tool that can do this - there are others, this is the only one I remember on top of my head and have used previously).

> If you are ok with re-installing windows 10 from scratch (losing all
>   your files, and programs)

Simply keep the Windows ISO / DVD that you can use to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I am okay with reinstalling windows from scratch. Then which one should I create between the recovery drive and the full installation drive?

Comment: Both are the same as far as I know. Recovery drive from MS is basically the Windows 10 installer DVD - but instead of default to install, it defaults to the troubleshooting mode, but you have option to re-install. If you plan to do a complete fresh reinstall, just keep a Windows ISO and make a bootable USB (using Rufus or YUMI) or if DVD is more your thing, then burn the ISO into DVD.